# Unable to connect to Azure SQL Server using ODBC ( The function is unfamiliar with the certificate authority that generated the server's certificate)

Tags: odbc, azure-sql-server

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL Server using ODBC.
I am getting an error when connecting as " **The function is unfamiliar with the certificate authority that generated the server's certificate**", the username and password are not getting validated.

[ODBC Connection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsHdN.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB9Vi.png)

Comment: Which tool do you use to connect to Azure SQL?

Comment: I am using Tableau to connect, the connection is getting failed when I am testing the connection at the ODBC DSN configuration.

Comment: You're using the AD password authentication, please change to MFA and test again.

Comment: Please update tableau to the new version.

Comment: Yes, it is working with MFA, but I cannot use MFA data source in Tableau Server.
For your info, the ODBC connection with ActiveDirectoryPassword is working in my local machine, but it is not working in Azure Virtual machine, giving the above error.

Am I need to add any certificates to Trusted Root CA ?

Comment: Can you thy this way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/tableau? Set the connection string with AD password Auth?

Comment: I followed the same steps mentioned in the above documentation, I have changed the Authentication from ActiveDirectoryIntegrated to ActiveDirectoryPassword.